# How to properly connect oscillator circuit to amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio, oscillator, wiring, synthesizer

edit v2:
Schematics:
[image]

The ic on the left is a 40106, and the thing inside is a Schmitt trigger with inverting output.

In 'edit v1' below you can see a wiring diagram.

edit v1:
Rough schematics and question:
[image: circuit]
[image]

Link to image if not shown: https://imgur.com/gallery/cFZNfXA

---

old version:

I built an oscillator circuit: It is based on Schmitt trigger inverters. It is powered by 9V DC. The output audio signal is present at a specific point, on a single wire, say wire A.

I also built the well known "little gem" amplifier. The amp has a dedicated input location where the audio signal should enter the circuit of the amp. The amp is also powered with 9V DC. (A speaker is also attached: positive wire to the dedicated positive output of the amp and negative wire to ground of the amp.)

So these two, the amp, and the oscillator are two separate circuits, isolated from each other.

When I connect wire A, the oscillator output audio signal into the input of the amp, two paths are joined at a single point, I can hear the music produced by the oscillator circuit - but with considerable noise.

If I power the two devices, the oscillator, and the amp, with the same 9V DC power source, the noise disappears.

I would like to keep the two circuits separate, and connect them through standard mono jack plugs, but I do not know how to do this:

I connect the output of the oscillator with the tip of the jack, but where do I connect the sleeve - that is ground? Should the two grounds, the amp ground and the oscillator ground be joined? What is the proper way to connect two such circuits, powered by separate power supplies?

Which one of these should I try:

1. solder output, wire A, to tip of jack, and ground, that is sleeve of jack goes nowhere
2. solder output, wire A, to tip of jack, and ground goes to ground of oscillator, and when I plug in this to the amp the two grounds are connected.
   ?

Many thanks for considering my question.

Comment: (The power comes from standard 9V batteries in both cases.)

Comment: Can you please draw a diagram, preferably with schematics or at least links to them, to see what exactly you want to connect and where.

Comment: @ssheep Sounds from reading that you connect only ***one*** wire in the first case you mention. When you then power them both from the same supply, you are effectively using two wires (the one wire plus then the shared ground line that you don't see but is there just the same.) So why not go back to the first experiment and this time also connect the grounds, in common, between the two systems?

Comment: @justme, I have added schematics.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I can connect the wires, even through the jack - jack jumper cable. But is it the correct way to do it?
E.g., imagine that there are two guitar pedals that each work from their separate 9v batteries. Both have input and output jack plugs (say mono). How these are wired? when connecting them are they chaining grounds? 

Please check the newly added schematics! Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @ssheep Well they obviously don't work with only single wire, any signal must have a reference, just like a multimeter won't measure anything useful with only one lead connected. But to understand if these two modules you built can even be connected together (without damage) the schematics of the modules are needed. What you added is a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Justme I have added the schematics. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Justme YObviously they don't work with 1 wire:the amp uses its own gnd reference when sending signal to the speaker (that is the speaker is connected to the gnd of the amp.) But this is not the same gnd that is being used by the oscillator. And this should be so (or is it?), because I planned these to be two separate modules: the amp can be used for many things, not just to connect the oscillator to it..

I am a mathematician (currently a postdoc, my area is probability theory), so I do not know how to do this stuff at all: but I would like to build a synth:) and this is where I am at:)

Comment: @ssheep Congratulations, Dr. ssheep! Sincerely. Given the probability theory area, I'd guess that you lean more towards applied math. Which means you may enjoy studying graph theory and in particular directed graphs and their application to electronics circuits. A very good book is Wai-Kai Chen's *"Graph Theory and Its Engineering Applications"*, 1997. By chapter 2 you are moving quickly. Of course, Gilbert Strang has repeatedly addressed these areas, as well. Later on in *"Introduction to Linear Algebra"*, 5th ed, he provides some coverage.

Comment: @ssheep Depending on how the incidence graph matrix is arranged (row vs column), KVL (Ohm's Law) is found in the columnspace and KCL is found in the rowspace, with the left nullspace providing the meshes and the right nullspace and the Rank Nullity Theorem providing the completed picture. I'm sure that even a glancing moment of your time and you'd understand why two 9 V battery systems connected only by one wire should not work very well. And it would be seen from a mathematician's point of view. Don't need to be an engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the actual question, the two grounds can and need to be wired directly together for the oscillator and amplifier to work. However the oscillator output is "too loud" for the amplifier input and may damage it unless you reduce the oscillator output amplitude. For TS plugs, tip is the signal, sleeve is the ground, and so on both devices the sleeve must connect to local grouns. Details follow.

So the oscillator outputs a square wave with levels of 0V and 9V, so the average DC bias is 4.5V. Usually it is a bad idea to feed DC into amplifiers.

However the amplifier has a DC blocking cap on it's input, which removes DC bias of the oscillator, and that's fine.

But 9V peak-to-peak square wave is just absurdly high amplitude for the LM386 chip. It is rated to handle only +/- 0.4V which is 0.8Vpp. And that's the absolute maximum rating. Assuming the LM386 output reaches 9Vpp with a 9V supply, and minimum gain of LM386 is 20, you need to divide down the square wave by at least 20 so it's 0.45Vpp max.

The LM386 amplifier circuit is made against normal manufacturer recommendations how to build it, this has got to be a circuit made by some audio circuit hobbyist with little understanding how to use the chip properly. However, it may suit for the purpose of distorting the signal in a way that sounds pleasant so ears.

The chip gain pot should not be directly between pins 1 and 8, as it will affect the DC gain and output DC bias. It will distort at high gains.

The amplifier seems to be specifically built as a guitar signal amplifier based on how the volume control is controlling the gain of the chip from 20 upwards, instead of being a standard line level audio amplifier.

So basically, if you want to use the guitar amp unmodifed, modify the oscillator output to look like a guitar and divide the signal amplitude down to same levels, maybe add an attenuation pot at the oscillator outputs.

Comment: Godlike! I am very grateful for your answer! So I learnt that it is a "guitar amp". I am gonna look for a general amp, or maybe I do not need one, since the levels are high enough (I only remove DC bias).

One naive question: If the two gnds are connected - as you suggest - will there not be a curent between GND1 and GND2? There could be a potential difference between 9V battery negative terminals, or maybe I am wrong... ? Thank you a lot for the detailed answer!

I cant cast a vote yet, but made a feedback!

Comment: @ssheep You have two isolated circuits as the batteries are not connected in any way and the potential difference can be anything and it does not matter. When you plug the cable and connect the grounds between batteries, that wire makes them to be at equal potential, and usually you define that as 0V or ground for simplicity. There will be no current and no potetial difference, not by itself. The only current that will be flowing in the ground wire will be the return current of the signal current.

Comment: So you are saying that it can not happen that, say Battery A with respect to Battery B has, say, +1 pikoVolts on its negative terminal? -- and thus electron flow happens from one negative terminal to the other negative terminal with some almost infinitesimally small magnitude (, making noise e.g- I do not worry about noise, I am interested in theory). Or it can happen but it does not matter because it is negligible? Or something else happens and I am lacking understanding?

Comment: It can't happen. The batteries each have 9V difference over their terminals but no relation between them until you connect them. The two batteries are two physical objects with no relation to each other - if you take one in your hand and walk on a carpet, you can charge one with thousands of volts of static electricty potential difference with the other battery. But as soon as you connect the negative terminals of the two batteries together, the static charges equalize and the negative terminals will be at equal potential with no current flowing after the potentials have equalized.